# Array traversal from a given index to the first

Tags: ada

I've taken an Algorithm course in which the instructor has decided to use Ada as programming language tool to test our understanding. The argument was that ADA language is quite close to the Pseudo code that appears in [CLRS](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms) book.

Below code is a snip for Selection sort in ADA:

```
   procedure Selection_Sort(Data : in out List) is
   begin
      for Destination_Index in Data'Range loop
         for Source_Index in Destination_Index + 1 .. Data'Last loop
            if Data(Source_Index) < Data(Destination_Index) then
               Swap(Data, Source_Index, Destination_Index);
            end if;
         end loop;
      end loop;
   end Selection_Sort;
```

The following:

```
for Source_Index in Destination_Index + 1 .. Data'Last loop
```

will cause traversing the array from given element (Data[1](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms)) to last element, however if I wish to traverse from the last element to the first, the following don't seem to work.

```
for Source_Index in Data'Last .. Data'First loop
```

It would be great help if someone can help me with this trivial problem, so that I can get on with the main problem at hand, which is learning Algorithms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A range `A .. B` having `A > B` results in an empty range. In respect to the `for` cycle, there's the `reverse` keyword to define a descending loop (end of [ARM 5.5 (9)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-5-5.html#p9)). Hence `reverse A .. B`, where `A < B`, will result in looping from `B` down to `A`.

The rest is left up to you for the sake of learning. In order to learn something, you cannot avoid learning at the first place.

Comment: It’s more that a descending range (`for J in 10 .. 0`) is empty, so that the loop is traversed zero times.

Comment: @SimonWright This is what I meant by “That would result in an empty range.” Feel free to edit and clarify my answer if it's not clear.

Comment: @SimonWright  I think according to note 7 (§ 12) the reverse range requires `A < B`, because the discrete subtype definition is evaluated regardless of the `reverse` keyword.

Comment: @SimonWright Your edit indicated `A` should be *greater* than `B`. However, in its current state I believe the answer is correct.

Comment: Ondrej, sorry! I hadn’t realised you’d had to correct my error.

Comment: @SimonWright No problem and thanks for your input :-)